# Error in function(i) : task 2 failed - "non-character argument" on R

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

What is Error in funcion_2(i) : task 2 failed - "non-character argument"??.

I'm trying to create a list of list , extracting words from xml files named on "lista".

```
cl <- makeCluster(mc)
registerDoParallel(cl)
list_of_list <- foreach(i=lista_xmls, .packages='XML') %dopar% funcion_2(i)
stopCluster(cl)
```

lista_xmls is ...

```
lista_xmls <- c("1.xml", "10.xml", "100.xml", "1000.xml", "10000.xml")
```

> class(lista_xmls[1])
>
> [1] "character"

funcion_2 is ...

```
funcion_2 <- function (archivo) {
#archivo = paste(archivo, ".xml", sep = "")

dataa <- xmlParse(archivo)

xml_data <- xmlToList(dataa)

titulo <-  is.vacio(xml_data$metadata$obaa$general$title)

t <- strsplit(titulo, " ")
t <- unlist(t, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)

descripcion <-   is.vacio(xml_data$metadata$obaa$general$description)

d <- strsplit(descripcion, " ")
 d <- unlist(d, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
 # d <- d[nchar(d) > 2]

doc = xmlTreeParse(archivo, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
 # node <- getNodeSet(doc ,"general")
  palabras <- xpathApply(doc, "//keyword", function(n) xmlValue(n[[1]])) 
  #df <- data.frame(matrix( c( titulo,descripcion,rep( 1, each=length(palabras) ) ) , nrow=1, byrow=T))
  #colnames(df) <- c("title","description",unlist(palabras))

  atsil <- c(t,d,palabras)

  #atsil <- unlist(atsil)
  atsil <- list(atsil)
  return(atsil)

}
```

Rstudio respond Error in funcion_2(i) : task 2 failed - "non-character argument", but I don't even know what does that mean, what is causing it, nor how to overcome it?

testing funcion_2 it does return a list with the words, soo I belive the error is in  %dopar% ,it doesn't work with %do% , nor ...

> results2 <- foreach(i=lista, .packages='XML') %dopar% funcion_2(as.character(i))

This is my first question in Stack and I'm begginer on R programing

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that if you use `%do%` instead of `%dopar%` your code also doesn't run without errors?

Comment: Does `funcion_2(lista[1])` run without errors? It's really hard to help if you don't provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Exactly Roland, in both cases it shows error.

Comment: funcion_2(lista[1]) does run without errors. Let me add more code to it be reproducible.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record>
 <header>
  <setSpec>SEB</setSpec>
 </header>
 <metadata>
  <obaa xmlns:obaa="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM">
     <general>
     <title>Advérbios</title>
     <keyword>Plano de Aula</keyword>
     <keyword>advérbio</keyword>
     <keyword>português</keyword>
     <description>Plano de aula que ao final o aluno será capaz de: </description>
     </general>
  </obaa>
 </metadata>
</record>

Comment: Well, first it has to run in serial (using `%do%`), then you can worry about parallelization.